# ASP.Net Core 3.1 Web API (ApiController), EF Core 3.1 {The system cannot find the file specified.}

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've done a couple of .net core api's EF Core before. In fact, I've created a working .Net Core 2.2 version here https://github.com/xmione/.Net-Core-2.2.

Now I tried doing core 3.1 for both core api and ef core. Each, of course has it's separate project.
I can do Add-Migrations and Update-Database fine. The database and tables will be created automatically. I can also access the weatherforcast api methods, it perfectly displays the data. UseInMemoryDatabase works fantastic also. But when I started doing UseSqlServer(). That's when I've encountered the error:

```
Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.
Unknown location

SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, bool breakConnection, Action<Action> wrapCloseInAction)
```

I can see created Database and tables both in Visual Studio and SQL Server Management Studio and I can play with it, adding, editing and deleting records. But when I run the API and test it. It fails and displays the error above.
Can someone point me to the quickest direction here. Thanks. My code resides at the below link:

https://github.com/xmione/ReactJS/tree/master/ReactJS.Redux.Web.API/API

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out how to fix this. I just followed the article at https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-api-ef-core-code-first/.
There's actually a source code at Github.com: https://github.com/CodeMazeBlog/ef-code-first.

I just followed the article, download the source code and compare it to my codes. I found out that I'm missing some important Repository classes.

My code in Github.com is already fixed, thanks to that article.
My Web API source code is at :
https://github.com/xmione/ReactJS/tree/master/ReactJS.Redux.Web.API
I hope this helps someone who needs it.